# Xamarin: BroadcastReceiver not receiving when the app is not running

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, xamarin

I'm new to BroadcastReceiver and I'm currently trying it out. From my understanding in Xamarin we'll only need to decorate our receiver subclass with the BroadcastReceiver attribute and Xamarin will generate the necessary entries in the manifest. This is what I have currently:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "myaction" })]
class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
}
```

Everything works fine when I'm sending the broadcast within the application itself OR when I send a broadcast from other application while this application is running. The thing is when I'm not running this application and if I attempt to send broadcast from other application (using the correct intent filter) I'll not be able to receive the broadcast.

I've done a little bit reading here on this issue and it seems that for native Java we'll need to explicitly declare / define BroadcastReceiver in the manifest itself for it to be able to receive broadcast even when it is not running. From my understanding this is not required for Xamarin so I'm kind of stuck right now. Do you guys have any insight on this?

Additional info:

- I was running on debug mode (visual studio)
- I have launched the application main activity for at least once
- Android 4.3

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare it from within a Service. The reason is given [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in Process Lifecycle section.

Regards.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.